# Nestjs: How to call 2 apis one after another with pormise?

Tags: es6-promise, keycloak, nestjs, request-promise

Can anyone let me know how I can call 2 API's on after another? Once `api1` successfully return username, call `api2` to get data by passing username. How I can acheive this?

**user.service.ts**

```
  async createUser(body: CreateUserDto): Promise<any> {
    const api1 = await this.keycloakService.createUser(body);
    const api2 = await this.keycloakService.searchByUsername(); // I have to pass username once createUser api call success 

    return { 
      api2 
    };

  }
```

**keycloak.service.ts**

```
 async createUser(user: IUserRepresentation) {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      const url = `${this.baseUrl}/admin/realms/${this.realmName}/users`;
      const auth = await this.getAdminAuth();
      const req = {
        url,
        auth: {
          bearer: auth.access_token,
        },
        body: user,
        method: 'POST',
        json: true,
      };
      request(req, (err, res, body) => {
        if (err) {
          return reject(err);
        }
        try {
          if (res.statusCode === 201) {
            return resolve(req.body.username);
          } else {
            throw {
              thrown: true,
              statusCode: res.statusCode,
              message: body.errorMessage,
            };
          }
        } catch (e) {
          reject(e);
        }
      });
    });
  }

async searchByUsername(username: string) {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      const url = `${this.baseUrl}/admin/realms/${this.realmName}/users?username=${username}`;
      const auth = await this.getAdminAuth();
      const req = {
        url,
        auth: {
          bearer: auth.access_token,
        },
        method: 'GET',
        json: true,
      };
      request(req, (err, res, body) => {
        if (err) {
          return reject(err);
        }
        try {
          if (res.statusCode === HttpStatus.OK) {
            return resolve(body);
          } else {
            throw {
              thrown: true,
              statusCode: res.statusCode,
              message: body.errorMessage,
            };
          }
        } catch (e) {
          reject(e);
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have the data available in the `api1` variable. Probably something like `api1.data.username` but that's an assumption. Try looking into what info is stored in the `api1` variable, you'll be able to pull the data from there.

As you pass back `req.body.username` you should be able to just pass `api1` directly into the function.

```js
async createUser(body: CreateUserDto): Promise<any> {
    const api1 = await this.keycloakService.createUser(body);
    const api2 = await this.keycloakService.searchByUsername(api1); // I have to pass username once createUser api call success 

    return { 
      api2 
    };

  }
```

though you should probably change that to `res.body.username` if you get the username from the response of the first API.

Comment: I'm passing `username` `return resolve(req.body.username);`. Can you please share some example?